# What does it mean $\mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix} I\\ M \end{matrix}\right)\cap\mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix} V\\ I \end{matrix}\right)=\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ and
> $\bf{V}\subset\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$. Decide whether
> $\mathrm{det}(I-MV)\neq0$ for all $V\in\bf{V}$.
>
> Observe that $\mathrm{det}(I-MV)\neq0 \Longleftrightarrow
>  \mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix}  I\\  M
>  \end{matrix}\right)\cap\mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix}  V\\  I
>  \end{matrix}\right)=\{0\}.$

Whenever I have to deal with image or kernel, I have a problem to visualize the meaning in my head. Here for example, $\mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix}  I\\  M\end{matrix}\right)$ contains all elements $\begin{bmatrix}  I\\  M\end{bmatrix}X$, where $X\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$, and $\mathrm{Im}\left(\begin{matrix}  V\\  I\end{matrix}\right)$ contains all elements $\begin{bmatrix}  V\\  I\end{bmatrix}Y$, where $Y\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. So the intersection of these two sets must contain only $0$, what does it mean?

Comment: it means there are no $(x,y)$ such that $x = Vy$ and $Mx = y$. In particular, it means that neither $MV$ or $VM$ have eigenvalue 1

Comment: @Exodd singular values of $MV$ and $VM$ are same, right. I understand that when these singular values are not equal to $1$ then $\mathrm{det}(I-MV)\neq 0$, Then the identity matrix inside the image is just to make $x$ and $y$ to be equal size and it has nothing to do wit the identity inside determinant?

Comment: You are talking about eigenvalues, and no, $MV$ and $VM$ in general do not have the same eigenvalues. The observation in the problem is leading you to consider the system $x = Vy$ and $Mx = y$, and check if there's a solution for some $V$

Comment: thanks, I got it now